# No matter what I do, snprintf() gives me a segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, printf

So I searched and looked at all the snprintf(), sprintf() and segmentation fault threads but am still nowhere...

Basically, it seems that the mere presence of a snprintf() statement is causing my code to have a segmentation fault. Long story short, yes, this is for homework...basically, I have to fill in missing code and am under strict orders to not touch the code that already exists. Here's what my code looks like:

```
        struct dirent* dirEntryPtr;
        struct stat statBuffer;
        char *yourFileName;
        while((dirEntryPtr=readdir(dirPtr))!=NULL)
        {
            int yourFileSize;
            memset(buffer,'\0',sizeof(buffer));
            yourFileName=dirEntryPtr->d_name;
            printf("Directory entry read...%s\n",yourFileName);
            snprintf(buffer,MAX_LINE,"%s/%s",DIR_NAME,yourFileName);
            printf("Printed directory entry to buffer...\n");
            stat(buffer,&statBuffer);
            yourFileSize=statBuffer.st_size;
            printf("File size: %d\n",yourFileSize);
            if(S_ISREG(statBuffer.st_mode))
                {   
                printf("REGULAR!\n");
                snprintf(buffer,MAX_LINE,"%30s (%5d)\n",yourFileName,yourFileSize);
                printf("[%s] %30s (%5d)\n",(char *)statBuffer.st_mode,yourFileName,yourFileSize);
                }
            else
            if(S_ISDIR(statBuffer.st_mode)){
                printf("DIRECTORY!\n");
                snprintf(buffer,MAX_LINE,"%30s (dir)\n",yourFileName);
                printf("[%s] %30s (dir)\n",(char *)statBuffer.st_mode,yourFileName);}
            else
                {
                printf("OTHER!!\n");
                snprintf(buffer,MAX_LINE,"%30s (other)\n",yourFileName);
                printf("[%s] [%s] %30s (other)\n",(char*) S_ISREG(statBuffer.st_mode),(char *)statBuffer.st_mode,yourFileName);
                }                   
            printf("Writing buffer \"%s\" to client...\n",buffer);
            write(clientDescriptor,buffer,MAX_LINE);
            free(buffer);
        }
        close(clientDescriptor);
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

All the printf()s are there basically for debugging. (Yes, I know, use GDB, but I could never figure out how that thing works despite years of instruction!)

Long story short, files in the current directory are read in, one at a time. The first file is usually one called server.c, which is always correctly identified as a "regular" file. However, right when that snprintf() line comes in is where the segmentation fault comes into play. buffer is a string declared (part of the code I'm not allowed to touch, but the instructions were specifically to write the entry to "buffer" using snprintf() -- in fact, the EXACT snprintf() command I'm using is what was given in the instructions!) and set to MAX_LINE bytes (80), which is #defined in an outside header file that's being included. I had a strnlen in there before for debugging purposes to confirm that DIR_NAME is one character and yourFileName, at least in the case of server.c, was 9 -- nowhere near the 80!

I even tried declaring a new variable and just writing one single byte to it via snprintf() but still got the segmentation fault! I've tried both with and without the malloc() command.

What else should I look for??? I did e-mail my professor about this but truth be told I have to submit this, like, TODAY (it's not due for a few more days but I'm going to be out of town) and just need pointers ASAP...but according to what I understand about C, this should work. In fact, it actually WAS working yesterday afternoon but all of a sudden it started segmentation faulting on me late last night. :(

Comment: Could you please provide a [smaller example](http://sscce.org/) of the problem if you can reproduce it?

Comment: Your example doesn't show how `buffer` is allocated (if indeed it has been allocated at all).

Comment: What is DIR_NAME? Maybe you need to be printing &DIR_NAME :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a probable cause:

```
printf("[%s] [%s] %30s (other)\n",
       (char*) S_ISREG(statBuffer.st_mode),
       (char *)statBuffer.st_mode,
       yourFileName);
```

This instructs `printf()`:

- to treat the return value of `S_ISREG()` as a pointer to null terminated string which it is not and will be either `0` or `1` (based on the following yanked from `sys/stat.h`):

  ```
  #define __S_ISTYPE(mode, mask)  (((mode) & __S_IFMT) == (mask))

  #define S_ISREG(mode)    __S_ISTYPE((mode), __S_IFREG)
  ```
- to treat `st_mode` as a pointer to a null terminated string which it is not (AFAIK the type of `st_mode` is an `int`)

To fix used `%d` as the format specifier instead of `%s` OR for `S_ISREG()` you could use ternary operator and return a string literal instead:

```
printf("[%s] [%d] %30s (other)\n",
       S_ISREG(statBuffer.st_mode) ? "regular file" : "not regular file",
       statBuffer.st_mode,
       yourFileName);
```

---

This is a mistake and almost certaintly the cause:

```
char buffer[MAX_LINE];

free(buffer);
```

**Only pass to `free()` what was dynamically allocated**:

> The free function causes the space pointed to by ptr to be deallocated, that is, made
>   available for further allocation. If ptr is a null pointer, no action occurs. Otherwise, if
>   the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by the calloc, malloc, or realloc function, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc,
>   the behavior is undefined.

Comment: The printf's above that one also have a faulty cast to char *.

Comment: Sounds to me like OP has a problem with the first snprintf. I guess either his buffer is not allocated properly, or DIR_NAME is not able to be used as %s (similar to some of your points).

Comment: @Scooter, yes it does. However hopefully the OP will be able to notice these after reading this.

Comment: Thanks for the reply...but again,the printf() was there for debugging; I was getting the segmentation fault before that was even in there. :(  (Plus, the segmentation fault happens before that printf() is even touched.) DIR_NAME is a string that was previously declared.

Comment: @dauber, post the declaration of `buffer`, `DIR_NAME` and of `MAX_LINE`.

Comment: @hmjd --  
   char buffer[MAX_LINE];

const int MAX_LINE   = 256;

#define  DIR_NAME   "."

Comment: @dauber, what about `DIR_NAME` ?

Comment: hmjd - yeah, the free() was there from when I tried malloc()ing buffer, which also didn't work. I tried your example printf, and here's the output when I run the program:

Directory entry read...server.c
Printed directory entry to buffer...
File size: 1634
REGULAR!
[regular file] [33188]                       server.c (other)
Segmentation fault

Comment: @dauber, you need fix _all_ of the `printf()` statements.

Comment: Okay, I bow to all of you...I got rid of the printfs -- and suddenly it works. :) THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

Another bug:

```
write(clientDescriptor,buffer,MAX_LINE);
```

is almost certainly not what you want if `buffer` points to a NUL terminated string. This always writes `MAX_LINE` characters and will not stop at a NUL. I suggest `fprintf` and friends (`puts`, `fputs`) to output strings.